# Getting multiple value from form in php

Tags: php

in my application, i am using form to submit using php but the problem is i have dynamic value in view that is according to option, values comes.Sometimes 2 textbox will appear or sometimes 4, 5 etc.
i am using to check the value by var_dump($_post), it will display all but the problem is how to get exact field with value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the name of the input fields / checkboxes as an array

```
<input type="text" name="stuff[]" />
<input type="text" name="stuff[]" />
<input type="text" name="stuff[]" />
```

Comment: @jensgram right :) no need to show it as deleted, just edit as you see fit.

Comment: Okay thanks.Now got the values but still have problem to get value from radio button.I used same code like name="stuff[]" but it gives only one value of multiple radio butoon

Answer (score 0):

use the

```
$_REQUEST['name_of_field']
```

it will be holding the value you submited for that field